# String not works with special chars

Tags: php, mysql, string, replace, special-characters

After a update i cant rename categories. In this string must be a fault:

If i use

```
 $categoryName = (!empty($categoryLang[$cat_details['category_id']])) ?  $categoryLang[$cat_details['category_id']] : $cat_details['name'];
  $category_lang .= ($table_name == 'reverse_categories') ? '$reverse_category_lang' : '$category_lang';
  $category_lang .= '[';
  $category_lang .= $cat_details['category_id'];
  $category_lang .= ']="';
  $category_lang .= $db->rem_special_chars($categoryName);
  $category_lang .= '";';
  $category_lang .= "\n"; }
```

i cant update categories with special chars. If i rename $categoryName to $cat_details['name'], it works, can update now, but now the categories special chars do not working.

Anyone a idea, how i can split this string?
THX 4 ...

Comment: looks like wrong quotes. do you mean `"$reverse_category_lang" : "$category_lang"`

Comment: Yes, '$reverse_category_lang' would literally give you `$reverse_category_lang` as the string. Presumably you want to see its actual value, so just drop the ' quotes (or change them to "). Also, I would guess that the first $category_lang .= should be just = but you still need to have a string value in it already.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if $category_lang is already defined but, have you tried to define $category_lang?

```
$categoryName = (.............    
...

//Define the variable to let you add more text to the text string 
$category_lang = '';
// Now you can use .=
$category_lang .= ($table_name == 'reverse_categories') ? '$reverse_category_lang' : '$category_lang';
$category_lang .= '[';
$category_lang .= $cat_details['category_id'];
$category_lang .= ']="';
$category_lang .= $db->rem_special_chars($categoryName);
$category_lang .= '";';
$category_lang .= "\n"; } // <-- this } is a part of a function x(){ ?
```